# How to get full screen applications menu/app launcher for elemetary os 5.1 Hera?

Tags: release-hera, themes, slingshot

I am quite new to elementary os and just wanted to know if there is a full screen app launcher available for elementary os(for Pantheon desktop environment) like just like the full screen start menu in windows or like app launcher in ubuntu and Kali Linux etc....

Comment: Not what I have heard of, but you can make the icons bigger in category mode.

Answer (score 1):

this is not available. elementary simply handles this in another way and only with the Apps Launcher.

Greetings